# reading key words from CSV file for imacros programming in nested for loop format

Tags: csv, nested-loops, imacros

I am using a CSV file as input with keywords to my imacros program. I am able to read only the column and generate the search output that I need. I want the program to read even the rows. The input has to be read like a nested for loop ware every row and column have to be inputted in the form 
         (1,2),(1,3),(1,4)..........(1,n)
         (2,3),(2,4)................(2,n) and so on.
Is it possible to read the input file with imacros in this way or is there any other alternative for this.

Here is my program that scrapes information using keywords and saves parsed information in another file. However, I want to use both rows and columns and input more than one keywords at once.

```
'VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
 TAB T=1
 set !extract_test_popup no
 set !replayspeed fast
 set !timeout_page 200
 SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
 SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 2
 SET !Datasource keyword.CSV
 Set !Loop 1
 Set !Datasource_Line {{!Loop}}

 URL GOTO=https://twitter.com/search-advanced

 wait seconds=1
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:ands CONTENT=
 {{!COl1}}
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Search
 wait seconds=1

 ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
 Set url {{!Extract}}
 Set !Extract Null



'Keyword Scrape
Tag pos=1 type=h1 attr=class:SearchNavigation-titleText* Extract=Txt
Set key {{!Extract}}
Set !Extract Null


'Main Heading Scrapping
Tag pos=1 type=a attr=class:AdaptiveNewsLargeImageHeadline-title* 
Extract=Txt
Set mainheading {{!Extract}}
Set !Extract Null

'Main heading URL
Tag pos=1 type=a attr=class:AdaptiveNewsLargeImageHeadline-title* 
Extract=href
Set mainheadingurl {{!Extract}}
Set !Extract Null


'Date of Post
 Tag pos=1 type=a attr=class:AdaptiveNewsHeadlineDetails-date<sp>js-nav* 
 Extract=txt
 Set date {{!Extract}}
 Set !Extract Null


 'Username whose post this article
  TAG XPATH=//*[@id="page-
container"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a/span 
 Extract=Txt
 Set username {{!Extract}}
 Set !Extract Null

'extract user name
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:@* EXTRACT=TXT
Set username1 {{!Extract}}
Set !Extract Null


Add !Extract {{mainheading}}
Add !Extract {{date}}
Add !Extract {{mainheadingurl}}
ADD !EXTRACT {{url}}
Add !Extract {{username}}
Add !Extract {{key}}
Add !Extract {{username1}}


SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=test1_output.csv
clear'
```

Comment: Q: Why did you include the "python" tag?

Answer (score 0):

I modified [one of my codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864617/imacros-read-from-excel/42875232#42875232) here:

```
' max column number in the CSV '
SET maxCol 3
' fake delimiter '
SET !DATASOURCE_DELIMITER "!"
' real delimiter '
SET rd ","
SET !DATASOURCE Address.csv

SET curRow EVAL("Math.floor(({{!LOOP}} - 1) / {{maxCol}}) + 1;")
SET curCol EVAL("({{!LOOP}} % {{maxCol}} == 0) ? {{maxCol}} : {{!LOOP}} % {{maxCol}};")

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{curRow}}
SET kw EVAL("'{{!COL1}}'.split('{{rd}}')[{{curCol}} - 1];")

PROMPT {{curRow}}_{{curCol}}_{{kw}}
```

Try how this macro works and adjust it to yours.